# Building a horizontal timeline - items are misaligning

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, timeline

As can be seen in this [Plnkr](https://codepen.io/rockstarjindal/pen/oPXqvm) I'm trying to build a simple horizontal timeline. The problem arises when one of the element text spans multiple lines or contains no text at all (see the second timeline in the plnkr). In that case the timeline looks broken.

How can I adjust this timeline css so that the line always remain straight independent of the length of the text elements?

My current html

```
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Titillium+Web:400,200,300,600,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<button id="toggleButton">Toggle</button>

 <ul class="timeline" id="timeline">
  <li class="li complete">
    <div class="timestamp">
      <span class="author">Abhi Sharma</span>
      <span class="date">11/15/2014<span>
    </div>
    <div class="status">
      <h4> Shift Created </h4>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="li complete">
    <div class="timestamp">
      <span class="author">PAM Admin</span>
      <span class="date">11/15/2014<span>
    </div>
    <div class="status">
      <h4></h4>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="li">
    <div class="timestamp">
      <span class="author">PAM Admin</span>
      <span class="date">TBD<span>
    </div>
    <div class="status">
      <h4> Shift Completed</h4>
    </div>
  </li>
 </ul>
```

My css

```
.timeline
  list-style-type: none
  display: flex
  align-items: center
  justify-content: center
.li
  transition: all 200ms ease-in

.timestamp
  margin-bottom: 20px
  padding: 0px 40px
  display: flex
  flex-direction: column
  align-items: center
  font-weight: 100
.status
  padding: 0px 40px
  display: flex
  justify-content: center
  border-top: 2px solid #D6DCE0
  position: relative
  transition: all 200ms ease-in  
  h4
    font-weight: 600
  &:before
    content: ''
    width: 25px
    height: 25px
    background-color: white
    border-radius: 25px
    border: 1px solid #ddd
    position: absolute
    top: -15px
    left: 42%
    transition: all 200ms ease-in 
.li.complete
  .status
    border-top: 2px solid #66DC71
    &:before
      background-color: #66DC71
      border: none
      transition: all 200ms ease-in 
    h4
      color: #66DC71

/// Layout stuff
html,body
  font-family: 'Titillium Web', sans serif
  color: #758D96

button
  position: absolute
  width: 100px
  min-width: 100px
  padding: 20px
  margin: 20px
  font-family: 'Titillium Web', sans serif
  border: none
  color: white
  font-size: 16px
  text-align: center
#toggleButton
  position: absolute
  left: 50px
  top: 20px
  background-color: #75C7F6
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove align-items: center from .timeline.

Also add

```
.author {
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```js
var completes = document.querySelectorAll(".complete");
var toggleButton = document.getElementById("toggleButton");


function toggleComplete() {
  var lastComplete = completes[completes.length - 1];
  lastComplete.classList.toggle('complete');
}

toggleButton.onclick = toggleComplete;
```

```css
.timeline {
  list-style-type: none;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.li {
  transition: all 200ms ease-in;
  -webkit-transition: all 200ms ease-in;
  -moz-transition: all 200ms ease-in;
  -ms-transition: all 200ms ease-in;
  -o-transition: all 200ms ease-in;
}

.timestamp {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  padding: 0px 40px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  font-weight: 100;
}

.status {
  padding: 0px 40px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  border-top: 2px solid #D6DCE0;
  position: relative;
  transition: all 200ms ease-in;
  -webkit-transition: all 200ms ease-in;
  -moz-transition: all 200ms ease-in;
  -ms-transition: all 200ms ease-in;
  -o-transition: all 200ms ease-in;
}

.status h4 {
  font-weight: 600;
}

.status:before {
  content: "";
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: 25px;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  position: absolute;
  top: -15px;
  left: 42%;
  transition: all 200ms ease-in;
  -webkit-transition: all 200ms ease-in;
  -moz-transition: all 200ms ease-in;
  -ms-transition: all 200ms ease-in;
  -o-transition: all 200ms ease-in;
}

.li.complete .status {
  border-top: 2px solid #66DC71;
}

.li.complete .status:before {
  background-color: #66DC71;
  border: none;
  transition: all 200ms ease-in;
  -webkit-transition: all 200ms ease-in;
  -moz-transition: all 200ms ease-in;
  -ms-transition: all 200ms ease-in;
  -o-transition: all 200ms ease-in;
}

.li.complete .status h4 {
  color: #66DC71;
}

@media (min-device-width: 320px) and (max-device-width: 700px) {
  .timeline {
    list-style-type: none;
    display: block;
  }
  .li {
    transition: all 200ms ease-in;
    -webkit-transition: all 200ms ease-in;
    -moz-transition: all 200ms ease-in;
    -ms-transition: all 200ms ease-in;
    -o-transition: all 200ms ease-in;
    display: flex;
    width: inherit;
  }
  .timestamp {
    width: 100px;
  }
  .status:before {
    left: -8%;
    top: 30%;
    transition: all 200ms ease-in;
    -webkit-transition: all 200ms ease-in;
    -moz-transition: all 200ms ease-in;
    -ms-transition: all 200ms ease-in;
    -o-transition: all 200ms ease-in;
  }
}

html,
body {
  font-family: "Titillium Web", sans serif;
  color: #758D96;
}

button {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100px;
  min-width: 100px;
  padding: 20px;
  margin: 20px;
  font-family: "Titillium Web", sans serif;
  border: none;
  color: white;
  font-size: 16px;
  text-align: center;
}

#toggleButton {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50px;
  top: 20px;
  background-color: #75C7F6;
}

.author {
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Titillium+Web:400,200,300,600,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<button id="toggleButton">Toggle</button>

<ul class="timeline" id="timeline">
  <li class="li complete">
    <div class="timestamp">
      <span class="author">Abhi Sharma</span>
      <span class="date">11/15/2014<span>
    </div>
    <div class="status">
      <h4> Shift Created </h4>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="li complete">
    <div class="timestamp">
      <span class="author">PAM Admin</span>
      <span class="date">11/15/2014<span>
    </div>
    <div class="status">
      <h4> Email Sent </h4>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="li">
    <div class="timestamp">
      <span class="author">PAM Admin</span>
      <span class="date">TBD<span>
    </div>
    <div class="status">
      <h4> Shift Completed </h4>
    </div>
  </li>
 </ul>
 <ul class="timeline" id="timeline">
  <li class="li complete">
    <div class="timestamp">
      <span class="author">Abhi Sharma</span>
      <span class="date">11/15/2014<span>
    </div>
    <div class="status">
      <h4> Shift Created </h4>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="li complete">
    <div class="timestamp">
      <span class="author">PAM Admin</span>
      <span class="date">11/15/2014<span>
    </div>
    <div class="status">
      <h4></h4>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="li">
    <div class="timestamp">
      <span class="author">PAM Admin</span>
      <span class="date">TBD<span>
    </div>
    <div class="status">
      <h4> Shift Completed</h4>
    </div>
  </li>
 </ul>
```